# How to make Suffix icon mark as green when user put correct length of input, Otherwise it will show red Cross Icon

Tags: flutter, dart

[FOR IMAGE CLICK HERE PLEASE.
**I want this Green tick mark converted to a Red cross Mark, whenever User doesn't  maintain the actual input length.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGPBd.png)

> I want Whenever User leaves the text-Form-field without entering the correct length of input(suppose max 6) the Green suffix button should turn into a RED cross suffix button.

```
  Widget userField(){
    return TextFormField(                                                                             
      decoration: InputDecoration(

        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color:Colors.grey),
            borderRadius:BorderRadius.only( bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20)  ,topRight: Radius.circular(20)   )
           ),


           focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color:Colors.green),
           borderRadius:BorderRadius.only( bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20)  ,topRight: Radius.circular(20)   )
           ),


        suffixIcon:Icon(Icons.check,color: Colors.green,),             //??????????????
        
      
        
        
        labelText: 'User ID',
        hintText: 'Enter your 6 digit user id',
        filled: true,
        fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
        icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
      ),


      keyboardType:
       TextInputType.number,
      inputFormatters:[                        
        LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(6),      
        WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
      ],


      validator: (String value){
        if (value.length<6)
         {
          return 'User ID must have 6 characters'; 
         }
          
          return null;

          
      },


    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
int textLength = 0;
```

And inside your TextFormField Widget

```
onChanged: (text){
  setState((){
    textLength = text.length;
  });
}
suffixIcon: Icon(textLength > 5 ? Icons.check : Icons.cancel, color: textLength < 5 ? Colors.green : Colors.red)
```

Comment: HELP HELP HELP ! the green suffix icon didn't change automatically even I put <6 number.

Comment: I forgot to change this line color: textLength < 5 ? Colors.green : Colors.red change < to >

Comment: take some time to figure out the condition, based on your suggestion. and VOILA it worked!!

Comment: set state showing error why ?

Comment: can show your code snippet?